# Initial scale, media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a native mobile website which should work on different viewport sizes, but instead of changing the attributes with media queries I want only to change the initial scale of the website.

How can I change the initial scale for different viewport sizes?
Works it with media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with javascript, I have done something similar like this:

```
 if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 480) {
            document
                .querySelector("meta[name=viewport]")
                .setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=0.4', 'maximum-scale=0.4', 'width=768');
        };
```

This is for a site that is designed for iPad but I want it to scale out for iPhones etc..

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most common way of setting the the "initial scale" is by instructing the browser to use the width of the device as the width of the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

To follow on to your secondary quesions, yes this obviously works well with varied viewport sizes by setting the viewport width relative to the device width, and is compatible with media queries.

This article provides further detail: http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/01/device-width-and-how-not-to-hate-your.html

Comment: Hi danwild; I found this article super userful for changing the viewport via a media query. However, as someone who's writing a media query for the first time in Wordpress, I don't understand the media features you need to embed the viewport spec into the media query... acceptable feature lists online don't refer to initial-scale, only things like aspect-ratio, width, etc. Do you have any recommendations around that?

Comment: What I mean by lists of features: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp